# How to clean up Spork output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spork, guard

This is absolutely annoying me to death what can I do about this?

```
Guard is now watching at '/home/pma/Sites/somesite.com'
Starting Spork for RSpec & Cucumber 
/home/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/test_framework/rspec.rb:2: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_PORT
/home/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/test_framework/rspec.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant HELPER_FILE
/home/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/test_framework/cucumber.rb:2: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_PORT
/home/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/test_framework/cucumber.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant HELPER_FILE
Using Cucumber
/home/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/test_framework/rspec.rb:2: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_PORT
/home/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/test_framework/rspec.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant HELPER_FILE
/home/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/test_framework/cucumber.rb:2: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_PORT
/home/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/test_framework/cucumber.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant HELPER_FILE
Using RSpec
Loading Spork.prefork block...
Loading Spork.prefork block...
Spork is ready and listening on 8989!
Spork is ready and listening on 8990!
Spork server for RSpec & Cucumber successfully started
Running all features
Disabling profiles...
Disabling profiles...
Exception encountered: #<Gherkin::Parser::ParseError: features/recruiting_goons.feature: Parse error at :6. Found feature when expecting one of: background, comment, scenario, scenario_outline, tag. (Current state: feature).>
backtrace:
/home/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/gherkin-2.4.6/lib/gherkin/parser/parser.rb:57:in `block in event'
/home/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/gherkin-2.4.6/lib/gherkin/parser/parser.rb:99:in `event'
/home/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/gherkin-2.4.6/lib/gherkin/parser/parser.rb:55:in `event'
/home/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/gherkin-2.4.6/lib/gherkin/parser/parser.rb:45:in `method_missing'
/home/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/gherkin-2.4.6/lib/gherkin/lexer/i18n_lexer.rb:23:in `scan'
/home/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/gherkin-2.4.6/lib/gherkin/lexer/i18n_lexer.rb:23:in `scan'
/home/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/gherkin-2.4.6/lib/gherkin/parser/parser.rb:31:in `parse'
/home/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/cucumber-1.0.2/lib/cucumber/feature_file.rb:37:in `parse'
/home/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/cucumber-1.0.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/features_loader.rb:28:in `block in load'
/home/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/cucumber-1.0.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/features_loader.rb:26:in `each'
/home/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/cucumber-1.0.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/features_loader.rb:26:in `load'
/home/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/cucumber-1.0.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/features_loader.rb:14:in `features'
/home/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/cucumber-1.0.2/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:132:in `features'
/home/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/cucumber-1.0.2/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:45:in `run!'
/home/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/cucumber-1.0.2/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
/home/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/test_framework/cucumber.rb:24:in `run_tests'
/home/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/spork-0.8.5/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:13:in `block in run'
/home/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/spork-0.8.5/lib/spork/forker.rb:21:in `block in initialize'
/home/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/spork-0.8.5/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in `fork'
/home/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/spork-0.8.5/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in `initialize'
/home/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/spork-0.8.5/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in `new'
/home/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/spork-0.8.5/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in `run'
/home/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/spork-0.8.5/lib/spork/server.rb:47:in `run'
/home/pma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1558:in `perform_without_block'
/home/pma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1518:in `perform'
/home/pma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1592:in `block (2 levels) in main_loop'
/home/pma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1588:in `loop'
/home/pma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1588:in `block in main_loop'
Guard::RSpec is running, with RSpec 2!
Running all specs
```

Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    abstract (1.0.0)
    actionmailer (3.0.9)
      actionpack (= 3.0.9)
      mail (~> 2.2.19)
    actionpack (3.0.9)
      activemodel (= 3.0.9)
      activesupport (= 3.0.9)
      builder (~> 2.1.2)
      erubis (~> 2.6.6)
      i18n (~> 0.5.0)
      rack (~> 1.2.1)
      rack-mount (~> 0.6.14)
      rack-test (~> 0.5.7)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.23)
    activemodel (3.0.9)
      activesupport (= 3.0.9)
      builder (~> 2.1.2)
      i18n (~> 0.5.0)
    activerecord (3.0.9)
      activemodel (= 3.0.9)
      activesupport (= 3.0.9)
      arel (~> 2.0.10)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.23)
    activeresource (3.0.9)
      activemodel (= 3.0.9)
      activesupport (= 3.0.9)
    activesupport (3.0.9)
    addressable (2.2.6)
    arel (2.0.10)
    bcrypt-ruby (2.1.4)
    builder (2.1.2)
    capybara (1.0.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      selenium-webdriver (~> 0.2.0)
      xpath (~> 0.1.4)
    childprocess (0.2.0)
      ffi (~> 1.0.6)
    cucumber (1.0.2)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.2)
      gherkin (~> 2.4.5)
      json (>= 1.4.6)
      term-ansicolor (>= 1.0.5)
    cucumber-rails (1.0.2)
      capybara (>= 1.0.0)
      cucumber (~> 1.0.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.6)
    database_cleaner (0.6.7)
    devise (1.4.2)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 2.1.2)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.0.3)
      warden (~> 1.0.3)
    diff-lcs (1.1.2)
    erubis (2.6.6)
      abstract (>= 1.0.0)
    factory_girl (2.0.1)
    ffi (1.0.9)
    gherkin (2.4.6)
      json (>= 1.4.6)
    guard (0.5.1)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    guard-cucumber (0.5.2)
      cucumber (>= 0.10)
      guard (>= 0.4.0)
    guard-rails (0.0.3)
      guard (>= 0.2.2)
    guard-rspec (0.4.1)
      guard (>= 0.4.0)
    guard-sass (0.2.4)
      guard (>= 0.2.1)
      sass (>= 3.1)
    guard-spork (0.2.1)
      guard (>= 0.2.2)
      spork (>= 0.8.4)
    guard-test (0.3.0)
      guard (>= 0.2.2)
      test-unit (~> 2.2)
    haml (3.1.2)
    i18n (0.5.0)
    json (1.5.3)
    json_pure (1.5.3)
    launchy (2.0.4)
      addressable (~> 2.2.6)
    libnotify (0.5.7)
    mail (2.2.19)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.6)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.16)
    nokogiri (1.5.0)
    orm_adapter (0.0.5)
    polyglot (0.3.2)
    rack (1.2.3)
    rack-mount (0.6.14)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-test (0.5.7)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.0.9)
      actionmailer (= 3.0.9)
      actionpack (= 3.0.9)
      activerecord (= 3.0.9)
      activeresource (= 3.0.9)
      activesupport (= 3.0.9)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.0.9)
    railties (3.0.9)
      actionpack (= 3.0.9)
      activesupport (= 3.0.9)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.4)
    rake (0.9.2)
    rdoc (3.9.1)
    rspec (2.6.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.6.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.6.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.6.0)
    rspec-core (2.6.4)
    rspec-expectations (2.6.0)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.1.2)
    rspec-mocks (2.6.0)
    rspec-rails (2.6.1)
      actionpack (~> 3.0)
      activesupport (~> 3.0)
      railties (~> 3.0)
      rspec (~> 2.6.0)
    rubyzip (0.9.4)
    sass (3.1.7)
    selenium-webdriver (0.2.2)
      childprocess (>= 0.1.9)
      ffi (>= 1.0.7)
      json_pure
      rubyzip
    spork (0.8.5)
    sqlite3 (1.3.4)
    term-ansicolor (1.0.6)
    test-unit (2.3.1)
    thor (0.14.6)
    treetop (1.4.10)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.29)
    warden (1.0.5)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    xpath (0.1.4)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  capybara
  cucumber-rails
  database_cleaner
  devise
  factory_girl
  guard
  guard-cucumber
  guard-rails
  guard-rspec
  guard-sass
  guard-spork
  guard-test
  haml
  launchy
  libnotify
  rails (= 3.0.9)
  rspec-rails
  sass
  spork
  sqlite3
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure which output you trying to cleanup, but here's what I'm seeing:

You have the standard spork messages that only happen at startup. The startup messages such as `Spork is ready and listening on 8989!` are a good thing since they tell you when spork is ready to start testing your files

Some messages about constants being initialized more than once. This may be that you are requiring something when you don't need to, but I'm guessing you'll only see them when you start guard.

The gherkin issue is with your recruiting_goons.feature file and is likely a formatting problem. You want that output because it tells you something is wrong with your test.

Answer (score 0):

I get similar warnings. Beerlington is right, mine are because I was requiring something when I didn't need to. Namely, I was requiring the model in each model spec file. I was doing so because when I run that model spec alone, unless I require the model explicitly, the partial code coverage results would end up not covering the model and produce incorrect results. When I removed the "require 'model'" line from my spec, the warnings went away. Note that for me, the file names it mentioned explicitly were my model names, which were being "required" redundantly.

Net net, look for why your "`rspec.rb`" and "`cucumber.rb`" files are required multiple times. Require them only once.